# Why the difference in speed to get groups in pandas

Tags: performance, pandas, group-by

Why the difference in performance on these three methods of getting groups from a 32m row dataframe in pandas.

```
df = df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).groups

df = df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).count()
df = df.index

df = df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).count()
df = df.drop(df.columns, axis=1).reset_index()
```

The last method takes < 10 seconds. I gave up waiting on the other two.

EDIT: added the square brackets which were missed.

Comment: None of these methods works (that's now how you use groupby). You keep assigning some results to a dataframe and it is unclear what you are trying to do. Please fix your code and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry missed off the square brackets when typed in here. a,b,c are columns

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is add `sort=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) (also add `[]`):

```
df = df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"], sort=False).groups
```

Docs:

> **sort** : boolean, default True
>
> Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. Note this does not influence the order of observations within each group. groupby preserves the order of rows within each group

Another solution is use [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html):

> Cleverly parallelizable operations (fast):
>
> groupby-aggregate (with common aggregations):
>
> **df.groupby(df.x).y.max()**
> **df.groupby('x').max()**

Comment: If dataframe is very large, i think better is use `dask`, please see edit.